# reverse-lookup Digital Object Identifier given table of citations?

Tags: publications

*I asked this question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9711539/199217) a few weeks ago, but have not gotten a useable answer, even after a colleague added a 150pt bounty.*

Is it possible to query the doi for each record in a table of citations?

I have a [table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ai_PDCcY5g2JdGN0VGxCd2NsNk5aQ0puUGlQZGczRkE&output=html) ([csv version](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ai_PDCcY5g2JdGN0VGxCd2NsNk5aQ0puUGlQZGczRkE&output=csv)) that includes the last name of the first author, the title, journal, year, and page numbers for each citation. I expect most (>90%) of the rows to have a valid doi, but using the [simple query uploader at CrossRef], I get a hit rate of ~7%.

There is also an XML-based query format that allows fuzzy matching, but this seems to have a limit on the number of queries that can be sent at one time.

The table is currently in MySQL, but starting with the .csv file would be a great help.

Comment: This might fit better on [academia.stackexchange](http://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @dan perhaps another site, but not academia according to their [faq]( http://academia.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: [Someone brought this to the academia meta](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/97/73), and the consensus was that it's on-topic there. One of the mods can initiate the move request.

Comment: @eykanal I don't think that is the case - the [only and accepted answer](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/98/258) says "The question on the scicomp board would not be appropriate here, but other questions in that area might be."

Comment: Hrm, guess I gotta learn to read the whole answer and not just the first part :/

Comment: @David: This question was merged with your question on Stack Overflow, because the standard protocol is to close or delete your original question before posting it on another site. Stack Overflow is probably the best place for it; it doesn't fit on Academia, Stats, or here.

Answer (score 4):

This is an open problem.  There are better and worse ways to attack it but, start by reading [Karen Coyle's summary](http://kcoyle.net/jal_34_5.html) of this problem.  The bibliography attached to that article as well is excellent.

In short, the problem of quantifying sameness between two bibliographic records is hard, and a substantial amount machine-learning research has centered around this topic.